# Converting big Excel worksheet to Data Table in a very fast way

Tags: c#, excel

I have to deal with very big Excel file. this file contains historical client data and I need to convert the Excel worksheet data into data table object. the data table object will passed to the another process for parsing.

I need a very fast way of converting worksheet data into data table. Any Idea about it?

I am currently using Aspose but it take around 23 Minutes to do the conversion. I try the OleDb it was very fast but it just work with physical file and required file path.my file data available as array of bytes. I don't want to write them on disk and use physical path in OleDB connection.

I have tried OpenXml but it was very slow (it took more then hour)

Using Aspose:

```
Workbook workbook = null;
loadOptions.MemorySetting = MemorySetting.MemoryPreference;
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file))
{
   workbook = new Workbook(stream, loadOptions);
}

var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

DataTable dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTableAsString(
                        0,
                        0,
                        worksheet.Cells.MaxDataRow + 1,
                        worksheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn + 1,
                        true);
```

took around 23 minutes

Using OleDB:

```
var fileName = "e:\\test1.xlsx";
var query = "SELECT * FROM [Data$]";
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString(fileName, "No") })
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = query, Connection = cn })
    {
         cn.Open();

         OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
     }
}
```

took around 2.5 minutes

I need a fast way to convert excel worksheet into data table for large Excel file (250 MB) less than 2.5 Min. The Excel file data available in Stream object.

Comment: Could you save the file as CSV file and read it as such?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using LightCells feature of Aspose.Cells where large files can be read in short time and then device own logic to fill the DataTable. Regarding the slow performance of ExportDataTableAsString(), this is already under consideration by Aspose.Cells team.

https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Using+LightCells+API#UsingLightCellsAPI-ReadingLargeExcelFiles:Example

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the LightCells feature. It was helping with the memory usage but not with processing time. The amount of memory usage reduced significantly but the whole process still took around 23 Mins.

Comment: I have added some more code as another answer in this thread. Could you try it and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Please use LightCells API to read data and export it to datatable. Remove all code about Aspose.Cells to export data to datatable  as it takes long time to export.

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime finishTime = DateTime.Now;
int columns = 442;
int rows = 181872;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] values = new string[columns];
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    values[i] = "test" + i;
    dt.Columns.Add(values[i]);
}
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
    {
        dataRow[col] = values[col];
    }
}
finishTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("load Excel worksheet data into Data table: (Aspose) " + (finishTime - startTime));
```

Comment: I need to get the column's name and row's data from Excel file I can not add a counter at the end of "Test". The real data are not "Test 1", "Test 2", …, I create a sample Excel file for you because I was not able to share the actual Excel file since it contains confidential data. Ahsan this code does not works for me.

Comment: @Hossein, Please create and share your sample file with us. We will look into it and provide a solution accordingly.